# How to resolve Ambiguous column name error SQL

Tags: join, ssms, common-table-expression, ambiguous

I am using the following query and getting the error, "ambiguous column name 'area'. I have done some reading and found that having it in the CTE and not group by/order by is the cause of the error. Not in my case, it seems. The end result of this query should appear something such as what is below. Any ideas as to where I need to add/subtract a mention of area?

To give some context, the reason for some of the elements is to have the result set contain a pre-determined list of sizeclassep even if there is no data. For some areas, there is no data. A population of 650 does not allow for some industries. Additionally, there are 29 columns in xyzfirms201701. Area, sizeclassep, ownership, and naicscode are just some of the fields contained in it.

The data is confidential and so regrettably no data can be offered

```
;with sizeclasseptable as 
(
select area,ownership,sizeclassep from (
select '01' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
union select '02' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
union select '03' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
union select '04' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
union select '05' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
union select '06' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
union select '07' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
union select '08' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
union select '09' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003') t0
cross join ( select distinct area from xyzfirms201701 ) t1
)

SELECT
'000003' AS area,
t2.[SizeClassep],
COUNT(*) AS [Number of Worksites],
SUM(t2.Employment) AS [Employment In Size Class]
 from sizeclasseptable
 inner join xyzfirms201701 t2 
on t2.area=sizeclasseptable.area 
and t2.ownership=sizeclasseptable.ownership
and t2.sizeclassep = sizeclasseptable.sizeclassep
GROUP BY
t2.area, t2.SizeClassep
ORDER BY
t2.area, t2.SizeClassep


area    SizeClassep Number of Worksites Employment In Size Class
000003  01  10866   13138
000003  02  1275    8322
000003  03  831 11192
000003  04  492 14694
000003  05  116 7783
000003  06  61  8876
000003  07  8   2809
000003  08  11  7909
000003  09  3   5322
```

Comment: Why do you need cross join (t1) you are not using any column from it? It would create duplicate records. The problem is: t0 and t1 have same column name "area". If you rename your area column in t0, it should work fine.

Comment: @Noor, so would I change it from area to areax? If so, it says invalid column name. Also, I will be editing it soon to give some context.

Comment: although I have offered an answer I don't know why you form a cross join based on [area] and a constant value also called [area]. seems weird to me

Comment: @Calflamesfann I have added my suggestion as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [area] in both the union `area='000003'` and you have it again in the `select distinct area from xyzfirms201701`. Which one do you actually want to use as "area"? Given that you appear to only want `'000003'` in the final result then use `t0.area` (see. second line below).

If you use a cross join in the cte, I presume you want all rows of that returned, so use a left join instead of inner join (? note, I am guessing this)

You are currently grouping by t2.area but don't include in the select clause. Either omit it from the grouping or include in in the select clause. Note because [area] it is part of the join it can only be whatever value you put into the CTE so I suggest you use `sizeclasseptable.area`

```
;with sizeclasseptable as (
    select t0.area,ownership,sizeclassep 
    from (
                  select '01' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
        union all select '02' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
        union all select '03' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
        union all select '04' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
        union all select '05' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
        union all select '06' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
        union all select '07' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
        union all select '08' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
        union all select '09' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
        ) t0
    /* cross join ( select distinct area from xyzfirms201701 ) t1 */
    )

SELECT
    sizeclasseptable.area  AS [area]
  , t2.SizeClassep
  , COUNT(*)               AS [Number of Worksites]
  , SUM(t2.Employment)     AS [Employment In Size Class]
FROM sizeclasseptable
LEFT JOIN xyzfirms201701 t2 ON t2.area = sizeclasseptable.area
    AND t2.ownership = sizeclasseptable.ownership
    AND t2.sizeclassep = sizeclasseptable.sizeclassep
GROUP BY
    sizeclasseptable.area
  , t2.SizeClassep
ORDER BY
    sizeclasseptable.area
  , t2.SizeClassep
```

---

**edit**

An alternative approach:

```
DECLARE @ownership varchar(20) = '50'
DECLARE @area varchare(20) = '000003'

WITH sizeclasseptable
AS (
    SELECT
        sizeclassep
    FROM (
                  select '01' as sizeclassep
        union all select '02' as sizeclassep
        union all select '03' as sizeclassep
        union all select '04' as sizeclassep
        union all select '05' as sizeclassep
        union all select '06' as sizeclassep
        union all select '07' as sizeclassep
        union all select '08' as sizeclassep
        union all select '09' as sizeclassep
    ) t0
)

SELECT
    t2.area
  , t2.SizeClassep
  , COUNT(*)           AS [Number of Worksites]
  , SUM(t2.Employment) AS [Employment In Size Class]
FROM sizeclasseptable
LEFT JOIN xyzfirms201701 t2 ON t2.area = @area
AND t2.ownership = @ownership
AND t2.sizeclassep = sizeclasseptable.sizeclassep
GROUP BY
    t2.area
  , t2.SizeClassep
ORDER BY
    t2.area
  , t2.SizeClassep
```

**edit 2**

Perhaps a method to reduce the number of query iterations would be to expand the grouping to all 3 of the columns used to select that data, and also broadening the way the where clause is defined. There is also a different method for produce the SizeClassep rows by using `values`

```
SELECT
    t2.area
  , t2.SizeClassep
  , t2.ownership
  , COUNT(*)           AS [Number of Worksites]
  , SUM(t2.Employment) AS [Employment In Size Class]
FROM (
    SELECT
        sizeclassep
    FROM (
    VALUES ('01'), ('01'), ('03'), ('04'), ('05'), ('06'), ('07'), ('08'), ('09')
    ) t0 (sizeclassep)
) sizeclasseptable
LEFT JOIN xyzfirms201701 t2 ON t2.sizeclassep = sizeclasseptable.sizeclassep
AND t2.area IN ('0003','0004','0005','0006')  /* ALTER THE LIST TO SUIT YOUR NEEDS */
AND t2.ownership IN ('50','60','70')          /* ALTER THE LIST TO SUIT YOUR NEEDS */
AND 
GROUP BY
    t2.area
  , t2.SizeClassep
  , t2.ownership
ORDER BY
    t2.area
  , t2.SizeClassep
  , t2.ownership
```

Comment: your code produces a result set and no errors. However, one strange phenomenon still to work out. The result set that your code produces is a multiple of 21 of the desired. for example, sizeclassep 01 produces 666456 (number of worksites) and 949116 (Employment in Size Class) when it should be 31736 and 45196 respectively. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Have you tried **removing the cross join**? nb: With no data to test with all I can do is "best guess"

Comment: It gives the following error when I remove the cross join from the CTE

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Comment: remove the WHOLE LINE not just 2 words

Comment: Ok, that works. For educating myself, do you have the previous iteration of your code so that I can see why this worked and the last one produced the inflated values.

thanks for your help. This has been quite the adventure.

Comment: If you look at the code now, it is exactly the same EXCEPT `/*` and `*/` before/after the cross join. Research what a cross join does (it MULTIPLIES the rows)

Comment: Have a look at this.  https://rextester.com/PZVT91288 From 10 source rows. I get 100 in the result using a single cross join.

Comment: thanks again for your assistance. Have about 400 more iterations of this to create. Need to really hunker down and dissect the code.

Comment: 400 iterations? I think you may need to ask more questions, perhaps there are easier ways to achieve what it is you are attempting. To be honest I don't see much point in parts of the CTE you are now using. I will add an optional alternative query soon.

Comment: There are 17 areas and 24 naicscodes per area. Each area has a breakdown of each of the 24 industries by sizeclassep. This report used to be generated solely through Excel but was a mammoth task. The purpose of the CTE is to have it always a value for each sizeclassep even if no data exists.

Comment: I have added an alternative. I do understand what the CTE does but 2 of the 3 columns are simply constants which can be replaced with parameters.

Comment: I will test this out and see how it goes. It sure beats the previous method which involved 960 separate excel sheets.

Comment: One (last) suggestion added. I shall have to allow you to investigate this on your own, or ask new questions as you see fit. I am unlikely to be available through this question for quite some time.

Comment: thanks for your assistance. I am in a much better place than 2 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

You have same column name in your cte as well as xyzfirms201701. You have to rename it in any one of the table for this query to work. Alternatively, you can just create alias column name as below. However, the cross join does not make sense here when you do not need any columns from that table. It just creates duplicate records.

The following should work. Notice the a1 alias for area column.

```
;with sizeclasseptable as 
(
select area,ownership,sizeclassep from (
select '01' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
union select '02' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
union select '03' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
union select '04' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
union select '05' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
union select '06' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
union select '07' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
union select '08' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003'
union select '09' as sizeclassep, '50' as ownership, area='000003') t0
cross join ( select distinct area a1 from xyzfirms201701 ) t1
)

SELECT
'000003' AS area,
t2.[SizeClassep],
COUNT(*) AS [Number of Worksites],
SUM(t2.Employment) AS [Employment In Size Class]
 from sizeclasseptable
 inner join xyzfirms201701 t2 
on t2.area=sizeclasseptable.area 
and t2.ownership=sizeclasseptable.ownership
and t2.sizeclassep = sizeclasseptable.sizeclassep
GROUP BY
t2.area, t2.SizeClassep
ORDER BY
t2.area, t2.SizeClassep
```